# How do I elegantly build this sort of mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, retopology

Good day fellow blenderers.

Not so much a question of ' how do I do exactly this thing?' but more of a ' is there a best practice approach' type of question.

When you have an irregular shape that you want to put a hole though, it's easy to just think of using the bool tool, but I've always believed that this just comes with another set of problems to fix.

So my question is - Is my attempt at creating the mesh below using only quads and retaining edge loops a proper one, or is there another methodology that can be used here?

My process is :

Draw the outer Ngon
Add a circle with same number of vertices as the ngon
Connect it all up
Evenly space verts on Ngon where possible

I've done it this way to try and avoid shading issues that you get with booleans. Am I overdoing it? Is there a better balanced workflow in these situations? How would you do it differently?

[image: Ngon to circle]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a good approach, you could use less edges if you use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier though:

[image]